# Solving systems with Groebner basis

Tags: polynomials, groebner-basis

Suppose that a finite set of polynomials in C[x,y,z] has a finite number of solutions (i.e. the generated ideal is 0-dimensional).

Suppose also that the Groebner basis with respect to lex order x>y>z is

[f(z), g(y,z), h(y,z), k(x,y,z)]

As well known, the system can be now easily solved: choose a root z0 of f, plug it into g and h and look for a common root (y0) etc.

The question is the following:
Is it true that for EVERY root z0 of f there exist y0, z0 such that (x0,y0,z0) satisfy the system?

In all the examples I have seen this is true, but I don't know whether this is true in general or there is a counterexample.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any root `z0` of `f` can be extended to a root `(x0,y0,z0)` of the system `f = g = h = k = 0`.

To see this consider that `Iz = <f>`, 
where `Iz` is the intersection of the generated zero dimensional ideal `I` with `C[z]` and `<f>` is the ideal generated by `f`. As can be seen in the proof that non-trivial intersections of `I` with `C[xi]` for all variables `xi` implies a finite zero set (see e.g. [here](https://www.kent.ac.uk/smsas/personal/gdb/MA574/week11.pdf), page 2 bottom and especially page 3 top), `<f>` contains a polynomial which factors only in (powers of) minimal polynomials of values appearing as `z`-value in the common roots of `I`. Since `f` divides this polynomial, it also has only roots that can be extended to roots of the system.

Comment: The link is not working anymore, can you update it?